# Logic behind building a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

This problem appeared on my test today and we still do not have an answer yet, I got confused while tackling the question, how should I approach this question and build the answer from the ground up?

In the first question I tried multiple joins (can not remember the specific way I answered).

The question in hand:

Assume the following schemas in DB:

```
cinema(cinema_id,name,city)
hall(cinema_id,hall_num,seats)
film(film_id,film_name,director,type,length)
film_hall(cinema_id,hall_num,film_id,date_hour)
```

1. Write a query that outputs the name and of the cinema and  how many movies of type comedy it displayed, per cinema.
2. Write a query that counts how many movies were displayed in cinemas that had more than 4 halls (I did not understand the question, I tried to display any cinema that had halls with id > 4)

edit:
For 1 I think I tried the following:

```sql
select name, count() 
from (cinema as c join film_hall as fh on c.cinema_id=fh.cinema_id) as cfh
join film as f on cfh.film_id=f.film_id
where f.type = 'comedy'
group by f.type
```

I do not remember the exact query but I think this shows the direction that I tried.

Comment: Can you include the SQL code you have already tried?  Stack Overflow tries not to be a free code writing service.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as I said, these were in an exam, ill try my best to remember what I wrote for an answer.

Comment: it is an introduction to sql.

Answer (score 1):

cinema(cinema_id,name,city) hall(cinema_id,hall_num,seats) film(film_id,film_name,director,type,length) film_hall(cinema_id,hall_num,film_id,date_hour)

1. Write a query that outputs the name and of the cinema and how many movies of type comedy it displayed, per cinema.

`select name, count() from (cinema as c join film_hall as fh on c.cinema_id=fh.cinema_id) as cfh join film as f on cfh.film_id=f.film_id where f.type = 'comedy' group by f.type`

2. Write a query that counts how many movies were displayed in cinemas that had more than 4 halls (I did not understand the question, I tried to display any cinema that had halls with id > 4)

`select film_id, count()
from (cinema as c join film_hall as fh on c.cinema_id=fh.cinema_id ) as cfh join film as f on cfh.film_id=f.film_id where c.hall_num > 4 group by flim_id`

Comment: How did you build the second query?

Comment: Doesn't the COUNT function take an expression argument?